# What is the different between Android JPEG and libjpeg?

Tags: android, jpeg, libjpeg

I came up with this question because now I am working on sending JPEG from Andorid to C++ Server. I found that when I encode YUV data(retrieve from android camera) -> BMP -> JPEG and then send to over the network. Then I used libjpeg to decode it. The libjpeg said it is not a JPEG format file. I tried to find any informaiton about Android JPEG but I dont have a luck. Could anybody explain the different between these two jpeg.

Comment: Post a sample image that fails to be read by libjpeg and I can probably tell you why.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about your issue, because I've had mixed experiences with JPEGs in the past.  I found some good links explaining your problem, like [this one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/uasLedtgymw)

I mentioned there being 27+ different algorithms for building Jpeg, and that they don't always play well with each other.  I know that you can have jpegs that fit the standard, as interpreted by one person, that can't be read in another persons program.  What you get is a big blame game about whose fault it is.

The bottom line is this-- if your libjpeg can't decode your Android-generated jpegs you have two options:

1. Use something other than libjpeg to decode them.
2. Put a version of libjpeg or some other library to code them differently on the android.  ([Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/AjVzQQ-C9Zo) is a link from someone who has a source code repository that could work).

Comment: Good luck.  You should post on here how things work out for you.